# How can I use Roughness Texture in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, textures, blender

I know that the Smoothness channel is actually the Roughness. But I downloaded some Models including Textures and all of them have a Roughness Image. But I can't read in the Image how big the Roughness (or Smoothness) is, so I actually don't know how big the Smoothness value should be that the Model looks perfect.

How can I detect this?

Thank you

PS: Look at my other question please, I asked it 2 weeks ago and I still don't have any answer: [Unity3d: Problem with Mixamo animations, they change position of Player graphics out of colliders and attached camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569657/unity3d-problem-with-mixamo-animations-they-change-position-of-player-graphics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smoothness and roughness are two ends of the same measure, normally using a scale of `0.0 - 1.0`. To be completely smooth, you would use a smooth value of 1.0 or a rough value of 0.0.

Viewing the image, mostly black indicates zero values, while mostly white indicates one values. Use that to determine which end of the scale you expect it to be using.

Using nodes or image editor, you would invert a smooth map before connecting it to the rough socket.

Mathematically that would be

```
smooth = 1.0 - rough
```

or

```
rough = 1.0 - smooth
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, now I understand it better. So I basically just guess, but I can see where it is approximately (more 0 or more 1).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Autodesk Shader provided by Unity. It supports roughness texture.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Shader-Autodesk-Interactive.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31164849)

Answer (score 1):

To add to sampler’s answer, if you make a graph in shader graph or amplify and just put the result of the roughness map through a minus one node and then plug it into the smoothness slot, that's a very easy way to quickly get the smoothness modifier in the material to behave as a roughness modifier.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most efficient way to do this is by using an image editor like Krita

Open the roughness map

Invert the colors using `CTRL+I` and save it as a smoothness map and use it in your shader

As an alternative, you can use one minus node before connecting your roughness map to your smoothness in the shader graph but it will be a little bit slower than the above method.